# How to highlight both a row and a column at once in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I can highlight a column using the syntax

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,0],[0,1]])
df.style.apply(lambda x: ['background: lightblue' if x.name == 0 else '' for i in x])
```

[image]

Similarly I can highlight a row by passing `axis=1`:

```
df.style.apply(lambda x: ['background: lightgreen' if x.name == 0 else '' for i in x], 
               axis=1)
```

[image]

However I can't work out how to do both at once; the problem is that when I use `applymap`, I only get the values, not the names of the series that they come from.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How about doing something like this? Enumerate the column and check the index while building up the style list:

```
df.style.apply(lambda x: ['background: lightblue' if x.name == 0 or i == 0 else '' 
                          for i,_ in x.iteritems()])
```

[image]

Or if you have color preference:

```
df.style.apply(lambda x: [('background: lightblue' if x.name == 0 
                            else ('background: lightgreen' if i == 0 else '')) 
                            for i,_ in x.iteritems()])
```

[image]

Comment: yeah this is the right way ... seems obvious now, just was having trouble wrapping me head around it for some reason!

Answer (score 3):

You can also chain your styles:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,0],[0,1]])
df.style\
.apply(lambda x: ['background: lightblue' if x.name == 0 else '' for i in x])\
.apply(lambda x: ['background: lightgreen' if x.name == 0 else '' for i in x], axis=1)
```