# highlight (color) a panda data frame row by index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-formatting

i have two data frame df1:

```
d1 = {"col1" : ['A', 'B', 'C'],
      "Col2": ["home", "car","banana" ]}

d2 = {"col1" : ['D', 'F','C'],
      "Col2": ["garden", "boat","banana" ]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)

new_df = pd.merge(df1, df2,  on ='col1', how='outer')
new_df
```

So what I am trying to do is highlight the third row "banana" that was found in the two data frames.
I was using the [Styling documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html) to find a solution but no luck.
I was able to highlight only a single row, but when I have multiple rows it doesn't work.
Please give a helping hand

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case you want to highlight two rows (say index 2 and 4) it is a almost a duplicate of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40335140/4819376)

```
new_df.style.apply(lambda x: ['background: lightgreen' if x.name in [2,4] 
                              else '' for i in x], 
                   axis=1)
```

If instead you are looking to highlight every row that contain a given name in a list (i.e. `lst = ['car', 'boat']`) you can use

```
new_df.style.apply(lambda x: ['background: lightgreen' if (set(lst).intersection(x.values)) 
                              else '' for i in x], 
                   axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you that, it did the trick. but how can i keep the coloring if i want to add another color in the dataframe?

Comment: @ilatikkral if you want to add more colors you could use an if, elif, else statement in your list of comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of questions link here regarding styling a DataFrame row, so I kept coming here despite the accepted answer not working for me, and no useful error message from pandas. I just came to point out that while the accepted answer may work fine for html, or Jupyter or whatever they're using. It does not work when applied to **Excel**.
For **Excel** you'll need the following:

```
new_df.style.apply(
    lambda x: ['background-color: <color>' if x.name in [2,4] else '' for i in x],
    axis=1
)
```

Note the use of **"backgound-color"**. Excel will not render "background" as you might expect

In addition, when working with Excel, you'll need to use a color name From Excel's list of recognized colors, Fiddling around with the above answer using "lightgreen" may give you black-on-black... probably not what anyone is looking for.